# Creating a Time Elapsed Field

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

Simple way to calculate the time from the nodes creation to now?

A lot of the time based modules don't seem to do this. 
(duration, time period, date, interval field, etc.)

Would Rules Scheduler be the best solution and have it react when a node is viewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would Rules Scheduler be the best solution and have it react when a node is viewed?

**No, that's the worst way to do it.**

All you need is jQuery to do it.

Lucky for you, there is a module that does this already, the [Timeago](https://www.drupal.org/project/timeago) module. Some more details from its project page:

> Uses the [jQuery timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to create dynamically updating "time ago" dates. That is, the plugin turns static dates like "October 10, 2011" into "10 minutes ago" and updates the time ago every minute. This allows you to include "time ago" dates in cached content for most users while degrading gracefully for users with JavaScript disabled.

**PS**: In your Content Type, when you create the time field, you need to select Timeago as your format instead of Date.